# Are uWSGI workers non-blocking?

Tags: uwsgi

I am starting to work with uWSGI and I wonder if its workers are non-blocking/event-based (like nginx is).

Supposing I have started uWSGI like this:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py
```

If the process inside the worker is waiting for IO, is it suspended in favour of another application request? Or does it block other requests?

If it does block with this setup, is it somehow possible to change the behaviour to achieve higher concurrency levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you have configured it, and on how your app can be run.

You may be interested in that page as it clarifies lot of bad behaviour of recent times (like applying a single event model independently by the application):

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/Async.rst

Comment: Thanks, I am just going through that document. And I have edited my question to be more concrete.

Comment: it is not clear if you have already read the link i posted, but your question should still receive the same answer: if test.py can be rewritten to be non-blocking (via specific api, monkeypatching or whatever you want) you can configure uWSGI to use that techniques, otherwise just use multiprocess or multithreading.

Comment: Ok, now I am trying to understand why uwsgi cannot be "non-blocking" by default in the same manner as nginx..

Comment: because it is hosting your app that could block (and i am pretty sure your app will block as you are asking for it ;)

Comment: So If I could start my application directly from nginx (maybe by using mod_wsgi) nginx would become blocking? That means nginx is non-blocking just for stuff it does on its own (like fetching files)? And If I added some blocking process to its event loop, its performace would be pretty much gone?

Comment: nginx strictly forbid you to run blocking part in it, that is why third party modules like mod_gridfs or the memcached ssl session store will never be part of it. So to answering your question, yes if you put blocking code in nginx it will die (it is not a matter a perfomance, you could simply destroy nginx when you put blocking part in it). The same apply to uWSGI, but if you are sure your app will not block you can run uWSGI in async mode using one of its alternatives loop engines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25039/discussion-between-clime-and-roberto)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Gevent in python and configure the gevent option in your uwsgi.ini.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Gevent.html

Remember not to use threads with gevent (thread=0).